# pasar de php a html

Tags: javascript, html

Aqui listo los clientes de la tabla

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla " ) ; 
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo "<table border = '0' width='100%'> n"; 
echo "<tr><td><strong>Cabecera 1</strong></td><td><strong>Cabecera 2</strong></td><td><strong>Cabecera 3</strong></td></tr> n"; 
do { 
echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['nombre']."</td><td>".$row['apellidos']."</td></tr> n"; 
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
echo "</table> n"; 
} else { 
echo "Texto si no se encuentran resultados"; 
} 
?>
```

Pero quiero pintar el html en javascript usando templates, me podrían indicar por donde iniciar?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con templates?

Comment: A que te refieres con templates?.
Si necesitas manipular el dom , basta con selectores en js

Comment: Hola, tienes que hacer que en el php de una repuesta json, en el javascript haces un ajax recibiendo el json, en el javascript creas el html con una función recibiendo los datos del json y lo imprimes para visualizarlo en la web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí esta el código de la parte de cliente que te permite usar templates.

Para el ejemplo use JQuery y JSRender

```js
var clientesRender = function(data) {
  if (typeof data === "undefined") {
    data = [{
      nombre: 'Jorge',
      telefono: '3057075510'
    }];
  }


  $("#container").html($("#templateClientes").render({
    detalle: data
  }));
};

clientesRender();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/0.9.84/jsrender.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container"></div>

  <script id="templateClientes" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <table>
      {{for detalle}}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{:nombre}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{:telefono}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {{/for}}
    </table>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Para la parte de servidor implementas un proyecto como Codeigniter (un MVC muy sencillo para iniciar) o sencillamente creas los scripts que retornen la data en formato JSON;

Aquí te pongo un script de ejemplo en php:

```
sql = "SQL" //ejemplo frutería: SELECT id_fruta,nombre_fruta,cantidad FROM tabla_fruta;

function connectDB(){

        $server = "SERVER";
        $user = "USER";
        $pass = "PASS";
        $bd = "BD";

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd);

        if($conexion){
            echo 'La conexion de la base de datos se ha hecho satisfactoriamente
';
        }else{
            echo 'Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos
';
        }

    return $conexion;
}

function disconnectDB($conexion){

    $close = mysqli_close($conexion);

        if($close){
            echo 'La desconexion de la base de datos se ha hecho satisfactoriamente
';
        }else{
            echo 'Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la desconexion de la base de datos
';
        }   

    return $close;
}

function getArraySQL($sql){
    //Creamos la conexión con la función anterior
    $conexion = connectDB();

    //generamos la consulta

        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die(); //si la conexión cancelar programa

    $rawdata = array(); //creamos un array

    //guardamos en un array multidimensional todos los datos de la consulta
    $i=0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rawdata[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    disconnectDB($conexion); //desconectamos la base de datos

    return $rawdata; //devolvemos el array
}

        $myArray = getArraySQL($sql);
        echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

Revisando esta información puedes hacer lo que quieres.

Saludos,